# Variable amount of OR, AND conditions on a lambda WHERE clause

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have looked at similar questions but none have really been able to answer my question.
All I want to do is make a select using lambda but the trick is, there is a variable amount of OR/AND conditions for the selection. My function receives a list of AND conditions and it should select based on that.

Here is what I have right now and it supports up to 10 AND conditions passed as a string to compare, but this code is terrible.. in reality it should be able to accept an undefined/variable amount of conditions.

Not sure how to go about this..
ProductTags is a list of tags.. if the product has all of the tags then it is returned.

```
public static List<product> FilterProductsByTagsAll(List<string> tags)
{
    List<product> products = new List<product>();
    switch (tags.Count)
    {
        case 1:
            products = Database.Products.Values.Where(i => i.ProductTags != null
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[0]).Any()).ToList();
            break;
        case 2:
            products = Database.Products.Values.Where(i => i.ProductTags != null
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[0]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[1]).Any()).ToList();
            break;
        case 3:
            products = Database.Products.Values.Where(i => i.ProductTags != null
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[0]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[1]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[2]).Any()).ToList();
            break;
        case 4:
            products = Database.Products.Values.Where(i => i.ProductTags != null
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[0]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[1]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[2]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[3]).Any()).ToList();
            break;
        case 5:
            products = Database.Products.Values.Where(i => i.ProductTags != null
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[0]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[1]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[2]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[3]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[4]).Any()).ToList();
            break;
        case 6:
            products = Database.Products.Values.Where(i => i.ProductTags != null
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[0]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[1]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[2]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[3]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[4]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[5]).Any()).ToList();
            break;
        case 7:
            products = Database.Products.Values.Where(i => i.ProductTags != null
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[0]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[1]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[2]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[3]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[4]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[5]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[6]).Any()).ToList();
            break;
        case 8:
            products = Database.Products.Values.Where(i => i.ProductTags != null
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[0]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[1]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[2]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[3]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[4]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[5]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[6]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[7]).Any()).ToList();
            break;
        case 9:
            products = Database.Products.Values.Where(i => i.ProductTags != null
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[0]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[1]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[2]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[3]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[4]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[5]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[6]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[7]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[8]).Any()).ToList();
            break;
        case 10:
            products = Database.Products.Values.Where(i => i.ProductTags != null
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[0]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[1]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[2]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[3]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[4]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[5]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[6]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[7]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[8]).Any()
                                                        && i.ProductTags.Where(i => i != null && i.Tag_name == tags[9]).Any()).ToList();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return products;
}
```

Thank you for trying to help out.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use LINQ?

Comment: Uh, wouldn't it be easier to just iterate over `tags`, instead of hard-coding loop steps depending on what the limit condition is?

Comment: OK, so my C# and LINQ are both very poor. I know the basics but don't have a setup where to test this, still it seems you just want something like `products = Database.Products.Values.Where(i => i.ProductTags != null).Where(i => tags.Any(tag => tag == i.Tag_name)).ToList();`

Comment: I know it would be easier to just iterate over, but I am really looking for a lamba or LINQ based solution.

Comment: @Tehavatar hi any success with answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
var allTagsProds = Database.Products.Values.Where(p => p.ProductTags != null && p.ProductTags.Select(pt => pt.Tag_name).Intersect(tags).Count() == tags.Count());
```

For each product, it selects the product tag names then intersects them with the tags list. This produces a list of product tag names that match the tags list.

Then it compares the count of this list with the count of the tags list and if they are the same, the product has all the tags. These are then returned.

Example using hard coded models:

```
public class Tag {
    public string Tag_name {get; set;}
}

public class Product {

    public ICollection<Tag> ProductTags {get; set;} 
    public string Name {get; set;}
    }

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> tags = new List<string> {"a","b","c","d","e","f"};

        var prodTags = new List<Tag>() {
            new Tag() {Tag_name = "a"},
            new Tag() {Tag_name = "b"},
            new Tag() {Tag_name = "c"},
            new Tag() {Tag_name = "d"}
        };

        var prodTags2 = new List<Tag>() {
            new Tag() {Tag_name = "a"},
            new Tag() {Tag_name = "b"},
            new Tag() {Tag_name = "c"},
            new Tag() {Tag_name = "d"},
            new Tag() {Tag_name = "e"},
            new Tag() {Tag_name = "f"}
        };

        var products = new List<Product>() {
            new Product() { Name="Prod1", ProductTags = prodTags },
            new Product() {  Name="Prod2",ProductTags = prodTags2 }
        };
        var allTagsProds = products.Where(p => p.ProductTags != null && p.ProductTags.Select(pt => pt.Tag_name).Intersect(tags).Count() == tags.Count());

        foreach(var prod in allTagsProds)
        {
            //Writes "Prod2"
            Console.WriteLine(prod.Name);
        }
    }
}
```